# Как правильно задать относительный путь директории?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
    $directory = "wp-content/uploads/2020/Painted_matrix";    // Папка с изображениями
    $allowed_types=array("jpg", "png", "gif");  //разрешеные типы изображений
    $file_parts = array();
      $ext="";
      $title="";
      $i=0;
    //пробуем открыть папку
      $dir_handle = @opendir($directory) or die("Ошибка при открытии папки !!!");
    while ($file = readdir($dir_handle))    //поиск по файлам
      {
      if($file=="." || $file == "..") continue;  //пропустить ссылки на другие папки
      $file_parts = explode(".",$file);          //разделить имя файла и поместить его в массив
      $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_parts));   //последний элеменет - это расширение


      if(in_array($ext,$allowed_types))
      {
      echo '<div class = "blok_img" >
                <img src="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'" class="pimg" title="'.$file.'" />
            </div>';
     $i++;
      }

      }
    closedir($dir_handle);  //закрыть папку
    ?>
```

Мне нужно вывести фото с директории, но я **не могу задать относительный путь**, то есть `$directory = "/wp-content/uploads/2020/Painted_matrix";` 
Код выдает ошибку "Ошибка при открытии папки !!!". Как задать относительный путь к папке?

P.S Этот код находится в папке темы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете использовать константу `ABSPATH`:

```
ABSPATH . 'wp-content/...';
```

Можете использовать константу `WP_CONTENT_DIR`:

```
WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/...';
```

Можете использовать ф-цию `wp_get_upload_dir`:

```
$upload_dir = wp_get_upload_dir( '2020/08' );
$dir['path'];
```

Comment: Я сделал так, но выводит папки еще и с хостинга
$directory = WP_CONTENT_DIR. "/uploads/2020/Painted_matrix";?

/home/mbmodelc/domains/model.com/public_html/wp-content/

Comment: Так и должно быть, все верно

Comment: Но src неправильный в img, выдает 404 на сайте

Comment: home/mbmodelc/domains/model.com/public_html эта часть лишняя в src. Как ее скрыть?

Comment: Выведите полный путь, это часть не лишняя. Если у вас 404, значит у вас неправильный путь указан)